# Joomla AJAX call losing Joomla database class

Tags: php, ajax, database, joomla

I am currently building some functionality into a **Joomla** build whereas results are returned from a database on a select box change.
The issue I am having is when I make the `Ajax` call I get a `Class JFactory` not found' error which I presume because the file where the php code is run is not considered to be inside the Joomla framework when the `AJAX` call is made?
I have tried to solve this myself but am having trouble.
Can anyone point me n the right direction as to where I am going wrong?

The `Ajax` call (inside index.php):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var url = "<?php echo $this->baseurl; ?>/templates/<?php echo $this->template; ?>/directory_code.php";
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        jQuery('#city').change(function() {         
        jQuery.ajax({
            url: url,
            type: "POST",
            data: jQuery("#city").serialize(),
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(data) {
            alert('data');
            }
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

And the function (inside a file called directory_code.php):

```
if(isset($_POST)) {
    if(isset($_POST['city'])) {
        $city = $_POST['city'];
        $suburbs = populateSuburbs($city);
    }
}   

function populateSuburbs($city) {               
    $db = JFactory::getDBO();
    $query = "SELECT DISTINCT suburb FROM vyj20_contact_details";
    $db->setQuery($query);
    $results = $db->loadObjectList();
    foreach($results as $key => $result) {
        $data['suburb'][] = array(
            $key => $result->suburb
        );
    }
}
```

Many Thanks

Comment: check this joomla doc- http://docs.joomla.org/Adding_AJAX_to_your_component

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code `defined( '_JEXEC' ) or die( 'Restricted access' );` usually restricts ajax

functions therefore you will need to use `define('_JEXEC', 1);`

Notice that you need to use `define` rather than `defined`, so if you haven't already done this, I suggest you try.